# is it possible to host aidl files at one place?

Tags: android, service, ipc, aidl

Currently I use a remote service in an android project. I defined the interface in two `aidl` files which are stored in the `/src` folder of my service project.

Now I have another project which binds to the service. For that I must, however, put the `aidl` files from my service in the `/src` folder of my application project.

[This act is described here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)

Now I have the the same `aidl` files two times. Imagine I have 100 client applications each in its own project. Now if I want to change something in the `aidl` file, I have to consider each copy of them which is not really nice...

Is there a way to centralize the `aidl` files?

Comment: In Eclipse you can put the AIDL in a 'linked source' folder which is referred to by both projects.

Comment: For more detailed explanation, see my answer to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656689/aidl-interface-between-two-applications/4657649#4657649

Comment: Thank you! I've created a new library project with only the aidl files and linked the other projects to it. Everything works fine.

Comment: @NickT, please, add your comment as a reply to the question and user3394244, please, accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a sdk project which contains your all aidl files and that sdk project can be included in all applications where you want to use.

sdk project can be created by changing code in `build.gradle` file from:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

to:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Now you can include all your `*.aidl` files under any folder as shown in file hierarchy in image below:

[image]

After creating this sdk project simply add this project in your other project by just adding following code in `settings.gradle` :

```
include ':sdk'
project(':sdk').projectDir = new File("../**location of sdk**")
```

Hope this helps.